# WebService WSDL discrepancy between 10.3.0 and 10.3.6

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, weblogic-10.x, weblogic11g

I'm working on a web service and I've encountered a discrepancy in it's WSDL when I deploy it on Weblogic 10.3.0 and when I do it on 10.3.6. Basically, there's a small variation that pretty much changes what, for example, soapUI interprets.

Here's the difference I found:

WL 10.3.0:
`<xs:complexType name="auth">

   <xs:sequence>

     <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="user" type="tns:userPassword"/>

</xs:sequence>`

WL 10.3.6:

```
<xs:complexType name="auth">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="tns:user"/>
</xs:sequence>
```

As you can see, in WL 10.3.6, it uses a ref instead, this is causing soapUI to display the request in the following manner:

```
  <ser:auth>
     <ser:user>?</ser:user>
  </ser:auth>
```

I'm using CXF and annotations for this implementation.

Does anyone have any clue about what's going on?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Regards.

Comment: That is abosolutely fine. You just gotta replace the `?` with your value. Am I missing something here? If you are expecting something else, please update the question.

Comment: I was expecting a complex structure on the request body, such like:    `<userPassword>
  <name>?</name>
`.

Comment: Please update the question with your expectations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to identify the issue. The problem is that on the WS interface, I was declaring one of the parameters as @WebParam(name = "user") which referenced none of the types I had. 
So I updated it to the one on my question and it appeared just fine on both WSDL and soapUI.